# SQL the column exists more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is working fine

```
SELECT i.*,o.*,p.*
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN oitems i 
ON i.orderid = o.orderid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN products p 
ON i.catalogid = p.catalogid
```

however i want to perform a nested select as an example this is giving the coulmn x exists more than once

```
SELECT AA.*, 
FROM (
SELECT i.*,o.*,p.*
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN oitems i 
ON i.orderid = o.orderid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN products p 
ON i.catalogid = p.catalogid ) AA
```

i know the second example makes no sense , but i need another select with groupping, is there a way to fix the coulm exists more than once error without having to specify the column names in the select statement?

Comment: [The solution is simple: Stop using `SELECT *`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `*`, you are getting the same column more than once in your output. To avoid, this, specifically state the columns you want returned, instead.

The culprits are likely `orderid` and `catalogid` which both exist in more than one table, but there may be others.

Comment: right, the error is about the primary key columns, but i wonder why there are no duplicate columns in the first query

Comment: There *are* duplicate columns, e.g., `catalogid` exists in two tables, and you are asking for both columns, which have the same name in the output, so "column exists more than once". Either alias the second instance of the column, or remove it, since it is the same value based on the `JOIN`.

Comment: so in the end writing all column names is the only solution?

Comment: No, but is the best and correct solution. You should almost always avoid `*` in production code. It is fine for ad hoc queries, or special code, e.g., ORM generation, but when in doubt, do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have mention column names specifically. I can see that you are using "*". you have to use like `select i.columnName,o.columnName` etc